# Live Video Streaming on Android 3.0+ (HLS and RTSP/RTP)

Tags: android, video, streaming, rtsp, http-live-streaming

I need some help getting started with HLS and RTSP on Android.

To test RTSP, I'm running a LIVE555 media server.  The server has the bipbop-gear1-all.ts sample file and index file that downloaded from live555.com.  So my URL is just  http://(myIP):80/bipbop-gear1-all.ts
On an Android 3.0 emulator, the browser shows downloading progress for a couple of minutes, and then nothing.  No update in the browser window, no Android download notifications.  It just stops.
On an Android 3.2.1 device it launches the video player, but immediately displays, `Cannot play video`, `Sorry, this video cannot be played.`
In a simple test app (downloaded from the Android issue tracker for issue 17118: Android 3.1 can not play HTTP Live Streaming), the MediaPlayer.prepare() briefly hits the server, and immediately throws an IOException with the message, `Prepare failed.: status=0x1`.  Logcat also shows, `error (1, -2147483648)`.

The same test app plays a local mp4 without problem, so I believe that's good.  On an iPad, the same URL plays the video, proving at least that my server is good.

To test HTTP Live Streaming (HLS), I'm using the bipbop sample served at apple.com:
http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8
httplive://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8

In an Android 3 emulator, the sample app begins to play the address with the "httplive" protocol, but it hangs.  With the "http" protocol, after MediaPlayer.start(), it hangs for a moment but nothing is displayed.  Then logcat shows:

```
W/AudioSystem(715): AudioFlinger server died!
W/IMediaDeathNotifier(715): media server died
E/MediaPlayer(715): error (100, 0)
E/MediaPlayer(715): Error (100,0)
```

and my onCompletion() handler is called.

On a real 3.2.1 device, the app using the http protocol behaves the same as it did on the 3.0 emulator.  httplive throws an IOException on prepare with the message, `Prepare failed.: status=0x1`.

In the browser on the 3.0 emulator, the http address brings up an audio player, which stops and then displays a toast message saying, `Sorry, the player does not support this type of audio file`.  The httplive address just goes to a Google search.

In the browser on the real 3.2.1 device, the http address brings up a dialog, `Complete action using`, with the choices:  `Music` and `Video player`.  Pressing `Video player`, I get, `Cannot play video`, `Sorry, this video cannot be played`.  Pressing `Music`, I get, `Couldn't play the track you requested.`. Again, this address works well on an iPad.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you with the RTSP Protocol.

For HLS, I was able to get the sample video from the Apple website working with an simple app built towards 2.3.4 and 3.0.

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(mVideoPath);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RTSP is supposed to be supported on android but seems to be broken , I recently had to play rtsp streams and ended up writing my own player using ffmpeg. there are a couple good projects you might try. Dolphin is one .

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are working on a project to learn about video players and streaming, it would likely be easiest to use an existing player to play your streams.

- For HLS (and MPEG DASH, the other main streaming protocol) ExoPlayer is the usual default player on Android: https://exoplayer.dev/hls.html
- For RTSP, ExoPlayer may work but VLC is another option: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-android-samples

From my experience, RTSP can be tricky so I've found taking a structured approach as outlined here is worth the effort: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67709149/334402