# How to play RTSP stream on android with low latency?

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp

I want to play RTSP live stream in app. The problem is that all methods I used doesn't work.
(URI definitely works, stream plays on VLC and MX Player)

I've tried using ExoPlayer:

```kt
player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(applicationContext).build()
val source = RtspMediaSource.Factory()
    .setForceUseRtpTcp(true)
    .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri("rtsp://$ip:8554/live.stream"))

player.setVideoSurfaceView(surfaceView)
player.setMediaSource(source)

player.prepare()
player.play()
```

but it gives me an error

```
me.mrcavas.project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ExoPlayer:Playback
    Process: me.mrcavas.project, PID: 14616
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions.checkArgument(Assertions.java:39)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspMediaTrack.processH264FmtpAttribute(RtspMediaTrack.java:173)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspMediaTrack.generatePayloadFormat(RtspMediaTrack.java:127)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspMediaTrack.<init>(RtspMediaTrack.java:66)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspClient.buildTrackList(RtspClient.java:291)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspClient.access$1400(RtspClient.java:66)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspClient$MessageListener.onDescribeResponseReceived(RtspClient.java:559)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspClient$MessageListener.handleRtspMessage(RtspClient.java:474)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspClient$MessageListener.lambda$onRtspMessageReceived$0$RtspClient$MessageListener(RtspClient.java:420)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.-$$Lambda$RtspClient$MessageListener$dJPB0r-FyeWq7xUwLx0FyxTnUk0.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

I've also tried:

```kt
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://$ip:8554/live.stream"))
```

and

```kt
player = MediaPlayer()

player.setDataSource("rtsp://$ip:8554/live.stream")
player.setDisplay(surface.holder)
player.setOnPreparedListener { player.start() }
player.prepareAsync()
```

but it gives me

```
W/MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (701, 0)
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: RTSP on Android is usually not that easy - I've found taking a step by step approach helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67709149/334402